# Count occurrences in vector of pairs

Tags: c++, lambda, count

I want to count the occurrences of same Points in a vector of pairs.

Here is my code:

```
vector<Point2f> points_1, points_2;

points_1.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 2.0));
points_1.push_back(Point2f(2.0, 2.0));
points_1.push_back(Point2f(3.0, 2.0));
points_1.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 2.0));
points_1.push_back(Point2f(2.0, 2.0));
points_1.push_back(Point2f(3.0, 2.0));
points_1.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 2.0));

points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 1.0));
points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 1.0));
points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 2.0));
points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 1.0));
points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 1.0));
points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 1.0));
points_2.push_back(Point2f(1.0, 1.0));

vector<pair<Point2f, Point2f>> point_pairs;
for (size_t i = 0; i < points_1.size(); i++) {
    cout << points_1[i] << " " << points_2[i] << endl;
    point_pairs.push_back(make_pair(points_1[i], points_2[i]));
}
```

The result should be:

```
[1, 2] [1, 1] - 3 Occurrences
[2, 2] [1, 1] - 2 Occurrences
[3, 2] [1, 2] - 1 Occurrence
[3, 2] [1, 1] - 1 Occurrence
```

I know you can use a map with a key (like a histogram) that tracks the occurrences and I tried something like:

```
map<pair<Point2f, Point2f>, int> pairToCount;
```

But I am not an expert at C++ lambda and don't know how to use this pairToCount

Comment: Keep in mind that you have floating point equality at hand. This means hat Point2f(1.0 / 3, 0) may not be equal to Point2f(2.0 / 6, 0.0) due to rounding

Comment: You can provide a custom `bool operator==` for your `std::pair<Point2f, Point2f>`, taking into consideration already mentioned float rounding, and then just use `std::count_if`.

Comment: Float rounding is not a problem in my case because my points are actually centroids of contours which I match and the contours are always exactly the same (just the matching method is different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point2f& pt)
{
    return os << "[" << pt.x << ", " << pt.y << "]";
}

bool operator < (const Point2f& lhs, const Point2f& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
}
```

You can simply do:

```
const std::vector<std::pair<Point2f, Point2f>> point_pairs /* = */;
map<pair<Point2f, Point2f>, int> counts;

for (const auto& p : point_pairs) {
    ++counts[p];
}

for (const auto& p : counts) {
    const auto& p1 = p.first.first;
    const auto& p2 = p.first.second;
    int count = p.second;
    std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " - " << count << " Occurrence(s)\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VitIbu)

Comment: When I try this I get an error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const cv::Point2f' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: because is needed bool operator<(const std::pair<Point2f, Point2f> &lhs, ...)

Comment: Do I have to overload the operator< inside a class or can I do it after `using namespace std` ? Never did this before, sorry.

Comment: @Grillteller: [Demo](https://ideone.com/VitIbu) linked. You have to provide more information about your error.

Comment: Ok your code is working in a clean environment. I guess the problem is that I am using opencv and the class `cv::Point2f` for my points. I tried changing the top part of the code from `const Point2f` to `const cv::Point2f` but I am still getting the same error. Thanks for the demo btw!

Comment: If you write operators, it should be in same namespace than the class, so in `namespace cv` (for ADL). Else you have to provide custom comparer for `std::map`.